# SFDX Scratch org Reports Deployment

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I have two questions

1). I have been trying to create a package in scratch org with all the Objects and the dependent files and the respective Reports too.

Configured the `Config file` based on the requirement say like **`PersonAccounts or StateAndCountryPicklist`** and so, in ***project-scratch-def.json***

When trying to deploy Reports with currency as filter condition - facing an error as `filters-criteriaItems-Value: Invalid currency`

```
"features": ["PersonAccounts","MultiCurrency", "StateAndCountryPicklist","SharedActivities"],
```

I have even enabled **"MultiCurrency"**.

Do I have to specify the multiCurrency records for Scratch org?

2). We are using Relate multiple contacts (EventRelation) - **SharedActivities** But this doesn't enabl the Related multiple Contacts too

Answer (score 1):

(1) **Multicurrency**

Try manually applying the **settings** instead of using the sfdx **feature**.  See [CurrencySettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_currencysettings.htm).

```json
{
    "orgName": "...",
    "edition": "...",
    "features": [...],
    "settings": {
      "currencySettings": {
        "enableMultiCurrency": true
      },
      "...": {}
    }
}
```

You may need to enable certain currencies like the currency being filtered in the report.  Though, I'm not sure if this is required.    Reply with a comment if you make progress and get a different error.

(2) **Related Multiple Contacts**

Similar to (1), manually apply the settings.  See [ActivitiesSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_activitiessettings.htm).

```json
{
    "orgName": "...",
    "edition": "...",
    "features": [...],
    "settings": {
      "activitiesSettings": {
        "allowUsersToRelateMultipleContactsToTasksAndEvents": true
      },
      "...": {}
    }
}
```